# Vue 3 Bootstrap 5 Navbar not toggling back to minimized

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, bootstrap-5

Im using bootstrap 5 on vue 3 like by doing the below

```
npm install bootstrap
```

and importing it in main.js like

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "bootstrap"
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
```

and now in my components I have a nav

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Title</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navContent" aria-controls="navContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="/products">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li v-if="isAuth" class="nav-item float-end ms-md-auto">
                    <a class="nav-link active" v-on:click="showLogoutDialog">Logout</a>                     
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And now the issue is that - I can toggle it to show the menu but cant toggle back. On looking into the inspect tool, I can see that the collapsing class gets applied but immediately disappears.

Thanks for any help in advance and please let me know if anything else is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eh.. solved it. So the issue is that if bootstrap gets included twice - the classes might not apply properly. So I had to remove the boostrap.js import. Now it works fine.

Comment: Same issue i had here. I was importing it in my index.html as well as a script accidentally

Answer (score -1):

I also got facing the same problems. please run your project editing code with double quotes to single quotes.

**Your code:**
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

import "bootstrap"
import "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"

**my testing code:**

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js'

import "bootstrap"  **** Remove this line and run the server again and check